# Gitlab error message: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed when running npm install on docker-compose build

Tags: git, docker, npm

I got an error message when running `sudo docker-compose build`

inside my Dockerfile, it was running:

`RUN npm install`

The error message says:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://git.mycompany.com/path_public/speakeasy.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.mycompany.com/path_public/speakeasy.git/'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I don't understand why running `npm install` requires git credentials.

I have tried to copy my local git credential to the docker container with `docker cp` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using a package installed from a private registry?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Yes, it is a private registry. I have fixed the problem will give an update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you are trying to install a library from your private registry but you have not logged in.

**1. let your git repo remember your login:** (15 mins)

run `git config --global credential.helper cache`

**2. copy and paste the command it shows above, in your case:**

`/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://git.mycompany.com/path_public/speakeasy.git`

This will ask you for credentials.
If you are using 2-factor-authentication, you have to put in your **username** and **accesstoken**, otherwise put in your **password**.